# why awk not working at ssh -V?

Tags: ksh, aix

command1:

`ssh -V`

output1:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

command2:

`ssh -V|awk -F, '{print $1}'`

output2:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

In Command2, why awk is not breaking  the output with **comma (',') delimiter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the output of `ssh -V` goes to stderr. If you want to process that output, you need to redirect it to stdout:

```sh
ssh -V 2>&1 | cut -d, -f1
# .....^^^^
```

Comment: Hi jackman, Thanks for your answer. I was struggling from longtime. But as I know command output should come in stdout, why this command goes to stderr. this is not an error right ?